# how to provide different login pages for different users?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi i have a login page when some one logs in he has to be directed to the pahe assigned to him by his role can any one help me doing this

```
     this is how my db table looks


        usertable                                 RoleTabel
-----------------------                     ---------------------------
   UserID|UserName|Pwd|RoleID                RoleID|RoleName
     1   |Anil    |123|1                       1   |Admin
```

like this can any one tell me how can i achieve and the query to be used ...

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: How are you reading your data in the application?  How are you going to decide where to redirect the user?

Comment: You do that on the page that you let him login, where is that code, how your users logged in ?

Comment: i want a query where in table i should get the role name so i can redirect him to the page...i am having problem in writing query..

Answer (score 1):

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
 // redirect to admin page
}
else if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("someother"))
{
 // redirect to someother page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using standard SQL (you can easily translate this to EF):

```
Select RoleID from <tablename> where UserName = 'Anil' and Pwd = '123';
```

This will get you the role id only if the username/pass combination is correct. 
Then depending on the number of roles you can either do case statements or if/else.